# pfSense join 2 networks

Tags: routing, router, lan, network-access, pfsense

I've got 2 pfsense boxes taking care of separate networks, with separate gateways.  We've managed to drop a cable between the 2 networks so would now like to join the 2 networks so machines on each lan can ping each other etc...

I've drawn a diagram - can anyone tell me if this will work?

Many Thanks
[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. You can do it by setting up a `Static Route` between your two gateways.

See the documentation here: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Static_Routes

This is the same scenario as my network where I had a LAN and a VPN. All I did was create a static route from my VPN subnet to my LAN subnet so they know to communication with each other. (Well, along those lines) Essentially making devices across two different subnets communicate.

**EDIT**

Which I just saw that was in your diagram.